# Servidor android

Tags: android, tomcat

Gostaria de saber como aplicativos como [este](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pas.webcam), disponibilizam um webservice através do IP do *smartphone*?

Existe algum Tomcat que rode no Android? ou algo que faça isso?

Ps.: O google me mostrou apenas o *Talking Tom Cat*, para *Tomcat Android !*

Comment: Thiago em principio essa aplicação deve ter um webservice algures a correr. Não deve ser um serviço no Android.

Comment: Thiago, deve existir um webservice rodando separado onde o app apenas acessa ele via ip para consumir. Você pode fazer deploy do seu WebService e acessar normalmente.

Answer (score 2):

Bibliotecas como OkHttp sobem servidores locais no Android que são usados para teste unitários. Como ela é open source, você pode dar uma olhada no código fonte pra ver como ela faz isso. Espero te ajudado.